# Adding a <li> to a <ul>-object in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html-lists, getelementbyid, createelement

I'm trying to create  a function in which a user clicks a button in order to add an item to an unordered list of items (without using jQuery). This is my js code:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     if (event.target.id == "add-item")
      var item = prompt();  /** returns a string variable */
      var itemlist =  document.getElementById("items");
      console.log(typeof itemlist); /** returns an object*/
     // itemlist.createElement("li"); /** A node is the generic name for any type of object in the DOM hierarchy. */
    
     
    });
     
     }
```

```html
<ul id="items">
     <li>The first item is free!</li>
     </ul>
    
    <button type="button" id="add-item">Add item</button>
```

Currently i get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: itemlist.createElement is not a function
    at HTMLBodyElement.

Note that i have also tried using querySelector to get the list of items, as well as the function appendChild() on the item-list, but none of it works...

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`createElement` is a method of the `document` object. After you have created it,  you can append it to another element.

```
var list_item = document.createElement("li");
itemlist.appendChild(list_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is a function on `document`, not on `itemlist`.

Use this instead:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = item;     // Set the text from the propt's return value.
itemlist.appendChild(li);
```